# Laravel edit records

Tags: php, laravel

my problem is when I try to edit one of the records in my KeyController it not only edit record that I want but all the records connected by local_id. Variable `$local` is only for redirecting to previous page to show all the keys.

I want to change type, quantity and intercom password. `id_klucza` after request is correct.

```
public function potwierdzenie_edycji_kluczy(Request $request,$id_klucza)
{
    $klucze = klucze::where('id_klucza','=', $id_klucza)->first();
    $klucze->typ_klucza = $request->typ_klucza;
    $lokal=$klucze->id_lokalu;
    $klucze->ilosc_kluczy = $request->ilosc_kluczy;
    $klucze->kod_domofon = $request->kod_domofon;

    $klucze->save();
    return redirect('lista_kluczy/'.$lokal);
}
```

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong and what I can do to edit only one record I want no everything connected to it?

Comment: Are you saying that all the records for that id are being changed? like I don't think there is a problem with your code, as you are only changing the type, pass and quantity.

Comment: I don't see how that would change multiple entries. `->first()` will give you one entry only

Comment: I don't know too but it happend all the time and I've no idea why :/